# how to use the state object outside the function

Tags: reactjs

i have an use effect function like this

```
function Content(filterdata){
const [certdetails , setcertdetails] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
  const getdetails = async () => {
  const details = await fetchCall(apicall,payload)
  setcertdetails(details)
}
getdetails()
})
```

Now how should i use the data in certdetails outside the content function

also how to retrive the data for each field

Comment: Have you tried lifting the state up?

Comment: It's better to fetch data outside and then deliver data to `<Content />` as props.